Migrate posgres 9.6 "main" folder to postgres 16
I am migrating the postgres version in my application from 9.6 to postgres 16. To do this, I have to migrate all the data in the postgres to newer version.
The approach I am trying is:

Take dump from the existing postgres container using pg_dumpall > pg_dump.sql and copy it to the host machine using docker cp.
Copy the dump file to new container running postgres 16.
Run psql -f /tmp/pg_dump.sql to restore the data in new postgres version.

But the last command fails with a lot of errors like:
psql:/tmp/pg_dump.sql:4992581: error: invalid command \N
psql:/tmp/pg_dump.sql:4992582: error: invalid command \N
psql:/tmp/pg_dump.sql:5477889: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "A41"
LINE 1: A41,tiger:county,"Merrimack, NH",tiger:name_base,Province,ti...
psql:/tmp/pg_dump.sql:5624109: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Cold"
LINE 1: Cold River",tiger:name_type,Rd,tiger:reviewed,no}
        ^
psql:/tmp/pg_dump.sql:5630110: error: invalid command \
psql:/tmp/pg_dump.sql:5631865: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Sa"
LINE 1: Sa 09:00-12:00",phone,+1-603-669-4956}

Is there any compatibility issue between the two versions? I tried pg_restore too, but that doesn't execute anything and prompt gets stuck indefinitely.

The errors you show are consequences of an earlier error. To get help, you have to show the first few error messages.

The errors shown are for the data in the COPY statements that load said data into tables. \N is what Postgres uses to represent NULL in the text form of COPY. It seems the data is not being parsed correctly.  The 9.6 to 16 jump should not be a problem in itself. pg_restore would not work as pg_dumpall outputs plain text and pg_restore does not work with that.  More information is needed: 1) What version of pg_dumpall did you use? 2) What are the OS and versions in use in the 9.6 and 16 containers? 3) Did the locale change in the containers?

I was getting this error because a previous sql command CREATE TABLE failed. This create table was adding new columns which were there in existing database.
This missing column caused failure of COPY command.
Due to large size of the error, I missed the actual failure.
Dropping the table before trying to create it again fixed the issue for me.
Note: I was fine with dropping the table which might not be the case with everyone, so ALTER table could be another other to modify table schema.
